# Changing The Image Source Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms

I have a snippet that is like this:

```
<div id="image_input">
    <img src="missing-image.png" name="image_comp" />
    <input type="text" name="image_url" size="37" />
</div>
```

I want that when someone unfocus `image_url` or even do a `onChange` event, a Javascript function called `changeImage()` be raised(this I already know how to do, now comes what I don't) and change the `image_comp` changes to the URL that is written in `image_url`. How to do this?

Comment: maybe document.getElementByName('image_comp').src = document.getElementByName('image_url').value;

Comment: `getElementByName` is not a function, only `getElementsByName`. This is because the name does not need to be unique like `id`. `getElementsByName` returns an array of objects with the specified name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByName("image_comp")[0].src = document.getElementsByName("image_url")[0].src;
```

if you have more elements with the same name you can loop trough them or use id's if you want to be sure it you do this for only 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="image_input">
    <img src="missing-image.png" id="image_comp" />
    <input type="text" name="image_url" id="image_url" size="37" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#image_url').bind('change blur', function () {
        jQuery('#image_comp').attr('src', this.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that's what happens when you answer before having coffee :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="image_input">
    <img src="missing-image.png" name="image_comp" id="image_comp" />
    <input type="text" name="image_url" size="37" id="image_url" />
</div>
```

You can define **ids** for both the elements and have this in your onChange function:

```
document.getElementById('image_comp').src = document.getElementById('image_url').value;
```